# Mathematical expression of largest $k$ numbers from $n$ numbers $(n>k)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-expressions

Can someone provide me a

Mathematical expression of largest $k$ numbers from $n$ numbers $(n>k)$

eg $S$ is a 3x3 matrix with [6  8 5 ; 3 4 6 ; 9 0 5] where $n$ = 9 (elements)

and I need to choose $k=2$, equivalent to (9 8).

I would like to get a mathematical expression for this.

Comment: I honestly don't understand your question at all.  What do you mean by "mathematical expression"?  What do you want from it?  What are you expecting it to "look like"?

Comment: @user1925750: Can you sort all of the matrix values from Max to Min and then pick off whatever $k$ number of values you want?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want :)

Comment: I am writing this on my report but I would like to include a mathematical expression but I don't know how. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: hmm...do you mean something like this: {$(a_1 a_2 ... a_k) | a_i \in S$ for $1 \le i \le k$ and $a_i > a_j$ for every $1 \le i \le k $ and every $a_j \in S$}?

Comment: I think that sounds OK. I'll copy that down :)

Comment: Here is some mathematica code as complexities arise with duplicates. get[k_, mat_] := 
 Sort[Take[DeleteDuplicates[Sort[Flatten[m]]], k], Greater]; m = {{6, 8, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {9, 0, 5}}; get[-2, m]; Out = {9, 8}

Answer (score 1):

Define an array $A$ with order $k$ and an array $B$ with order $n$. Fill $B$ with the numbers you said "$n$ numbers. Also add two other variables $minA$ and $indexOfMinA$. Add first element of $B$ to $A$. Make $minA = b_1$ and $indexOfMinA=1$. Then add the rest of first $k$ elements of $B$ to $A$ and when you do this process, check for each $b_i$ if they are smaller than $minA$, if it is, make $minA=b_i$ and $indexOfMinA=j$ where $a_j$ is the place where you've added $b_i$ in $A$. Then From $i=k+1$ to $i=n$ search every number $b_i$, where $b_i\in B$. Whenever you see a $b_i >minA$, make $minA=b_i$ and $indexOfMinA = j$. Then replace $a_{indexOfMinA}$ with $b_i$. You have you array.